# Unable to convert XML String to JAXB object properly

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have my XML:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <pfx:UpdateOrderPickedStatusRequest xmlns:flt="http://www.example.com"
xmlns:hdr="http://www.example2.com/Header/datatypes/MessageHeader/1.4/"
xmlns:pfx="http://www.example3.com/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xmlns.djd.com/new/final.xsd ">
            <hdr:MessageHeader>
                <hdr:SubId>ABC</hdr:SubId>
                <hdr:CnsmrId>PQR</hdr:CnsmrId>
                <hdr:SrvcNm>QWERTY</hdr:SrvcNm>
                <hdr:TranId>1234</hdr:TranId>
                <hdr:Version>2.7</hdr:Version>
                </hdr:MessageHeader>
            <pfx:MessageBody>
                <pfx:customerOrder>
                    <pfx:orderHeader>
                        <pfx:orderNumber>6666111999</pfx:orderNumber>
                    </pfx:orderHeader>
                </pfx:customerOrder>
        </pfx:MessageBody>
        </pfx:UpdateOrderPickedStatusRequest>
```

Update.xsd:

```
  <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
               elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified" 
               targetNamespace="http://www.example44.com"
               xmlns:pfx="http://www.example3.com/"
               version="2.7" xmlns:hdr="http://www.example2.com/Header/datatypes/MessageHeader/1.4/"
               xmlns:flt="http://www.example.com">
              <xsd:import namespace="http://www.example2.com/Header/datatypes/MessageHeader/1.4/"
                 schemaLocation="MessageHeader.xsd"/>

        <xsd:complexType name="CustomerOrder">
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="orderHeader" type="pfx:OrderHeader"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:schema>
```

MessageHeader.xsd:

```
 <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
                   elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified" 
                   targetNamespace="http://www.example44.com"
                   xmlns:pfx="http://www.example3.com/"
                   version="2.7" xmlns:hdr="http://www.example2.com/Header/datatypes/MessageHeader/1.4/"
                   xmlns:flt="http://www.example.com">
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.example44.com/"
     schemaLocation="Update.xsd"/>

 <xsd:simpleType name="alpha255">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:maxLength value="255"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:element name="MessageHeader" type="hdr:MessageHeader"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="MessageHeader">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="SubId" type="pfx:alpha255"/>
      <xsd:element name="CnsmrId" type="pfx:alpha255"/>
      <xsd:element name="SrvcNm" type="pfx:alpha255"/>
      <xsd:element name="AppId" type="pfx:alpha255" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xsd:element name="TranId" type="pfx:alpha255" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xsd:element name="UsrNm" type="pfx:alpha255" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xsd:element name="Pwd" type="pfx:alpha255" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xsd:element name="SrcSysId" type="pfx:alpha255" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xsd:element name="Version" type="pfx:alpha255"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

MessageHeader.java :

```
public class MessageHeader {

    @XmlElement(name = "SubId", required = true)
    protected String subId;
    @XmlElement(name = "CnsmrId", required = true)
    protected String cnsmrId;
    @XmlElement(name = "SrvcNm", required = true)
    protected String srvcNm;
    @XmlElement(name = "AppId")
    protected String appId;
    @XmlElement(name = "TranId")
    protected String tranId;
    @XmlElement(name = "UsrNm")
    protected String usrNm;
    @XmlElement(name = "Pwd")
    protected String pwd;
    @XmlElement(name = "SrcSysId")
    protected String srcSysId;
    @XmlElement(name = "Version", required = true)
    protected String version;
    @XmlElement(name = "ConfCd")
    protected String confCd;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the subId property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getSubId() {
        return subId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the subId property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setSubId(String value) {
        this.subId = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the cnsmrId property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getCnsmrId() {
        return cnsmrId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the cnsmrId property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setCnsmrId(String value) {
        this.cnsmrId = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the srvcNm property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getSrvcNm() {
        return srvcNm;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the srvcNm property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setSrvcNm(String value) {
        this.srvcNm = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the appId property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getAppId() {
        return appId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the appId property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setAppId(String value) {
        this.appId = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the tranId property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getTranId() {
        return tranId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the tranId property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setTranId(String value) {
        this.tranId = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the usrNm property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getUsrNm() {
        return usrNm;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the usrNm property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setUsrNm(String value) {
        this.usrNm = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the pwd property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getPwd() {
        return pwd;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the pwd property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setPwd(String value) {
        this.pwd = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the srcSysId property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getSrcSysId() {
        return srcSysId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the srcSysId property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setSrcSysId(String value) {
        this.srcSysId = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the version property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the version property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setVersion(String value) {
        this.version = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the confCd property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getConfCd() {
        return confCd;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the confCd property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setConfCd(String value) {
        this.confCd = value;
    }

}
```

Suppose I have my above XML in a string called xmlMessage, I am trying to convert it into JAXB object like this :

```
StringReader xmlReader = new StringReader(xmlMessage);
            MessageHeader msghdr = JAXB.unmarshal(xmlReader, MessageHeader.class);

            System.out.println(msghdr.getVersion());
```

But the `System.out.println(msghdr.getVersion());` prints `null`. Can you please point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to deserialize the whole XML document into a `MessageHeader`, when what you want to do is to deserialize just the `<hdr:MessageHeader>` child element into a `MessageHeader`.

The root element of your XML document, `<pfx:UpdateOrderPickedStatusRequest>`, has no `<hdr:Version>` element, nor does it have any child elements whose names match annotations in your `MessageHeader` class.  (It just has two child elements, `MessageHeader` and `MessageBody`.)  JAXB tries to match up child elements of `<pfx:UpdateOrderPickedStatusRequest>` with properties of your `MessageHeader` object, but JAXB isn't able to match anything.  As a result, all the properties of your `MessageHeader` remain with their default value of `null`.

What you need to do instead is to create a class that represents the root element of the XML document, for example:

```
public class UpdateOrderPickedStatusRequest {

    private MessageHeader header;

    @XmlElement(name = "MessageHeader")
    public MessageHeader getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public void setHeader(MessageHeader header) {
        this.header = header;
    }
}
```

This class has a child property for the `MessageHeader` sub-element.

You then use JAXB to deserialize your XML document into an `UpdateOrderPickedStatusRequest` object, instead of into a `MessageHeader` object:

```
    UpdateOrderPickedStatusRequest request = JAXB.unmarshal(xmlReader, UpdateOrderPickedStatusRequest.class);
```

You should then find that JAXB deserializes the contents of the `<hdr:MessageHeader>` sub-element into a `MessageHeader` sub-object, and so the various properties in the `MessageHeader` object should get set.  You can then grab the header from the request object you get from the line above, and within the header should be the version.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) This not only helped but also cleared my concepts regarding JAXB objects